# Get value from apscustomer_entity_varchar

Tags: database

I created a customer attribute in backend magento, but I want to show this attribute to the user so that he can alter its value in the frontend. My input field is being displayed in the frontend, but the value is not there. I am not able to get this value. I found that the value that I need to display is in the apscustomer_entity_varchar table and the collumn is called 'value'. How can I get that value from that table? I am trying this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $data) {
  return $data;
}
```

How can I get the value collumn from my apscustomer_entity_varchar table?